# How to handle Autocomplete Textview item selection?

Tags: android, arrays, list, autocompletetextview

I'm using autocomplete to show a list of dogs from database.

Suppose I have a DogList with 3 objects: Dog1,Dog2,Dog3 and a String array "dogNames" with each name of these dogs (I'm fetching autocomplete adapter with this array).

When an item is selected while full list is shown I can handle which dog was selected by getting it from DogList using autocomplete selected index, since "DogList" and "dogNames" array have the same size:

```
    Dog newDog = new Dog();

    autoComplete_dogs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            newDog = dogList.get(i);



        }
```

The problem is when I type Dog3 and click it, selected index is 0, which gives Dog1 but not Dog3, since Dog1 has index 0 in DogList.

How should I dinamically sort DogList so it follows autocomplete result list, and every time I try to get a dog from DogList using autocomplete index I get the right object?

Comment: Have one list only - of Dog objects which have a name member.

Comment: A string array is needed for autocomplete adapter manipulation. And yes, Dog objects have name attribute,

Comment: @IagoBrayham you souldn't sort/change your DogList this is a wrong aproach.

Comment: You don't need a string array. Simply pass a `Dog` array to a custom `ArrayAdapter`, of which you overwrite only the `getView` method.

Comment: @kalabalik What should I change on getView method?

Comment: @kalabalik It worked. Thank you all, guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onItemClick method use this

```
newDog = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

Comment: This will only work if I use a custom adapter, right? Cause current adapter takes a String array, not a list

Comment: @IagoBrayham as i remember getItemAtPosition method have generic type thet depends on type used in adapter.

Comment: Added a custom DogAdapter extending Array Adapter and it worked properly. Thanks!